# Error de compilación con Crystal cannot find -lz

Tags: crystal-lang

Hace poco eh instalado crystal, la instalción salio sin problemas. Me puse a probar un poco este lenguaje y todo iba muy bien hasta que empeze a tener este error, especificamente cuando intento crear el servidor Http, Si alguien me puediera ayudar ah saber cual es error, imagino que es con alguna dependecia u algo asi, pero no estoy seguro. Posdata este código lo estoy probando en Kali Linux por si alguien le intereza, eh provado este código con el bash de ubuntu en windows y no eh tenido problema.

> cannot find -lz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error indica que te falta la librería `zlib`. Para poder ejecutar y compilar el código de ejemplo que has puesto es necesario instalar lo siguiente en Debian y derivados (como lo es Kali Linux):

```
apt install zlib1g-dev libssl1.0-dev
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: @AllanGarcia si la respuesta te ayudó, [no te olvides de aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/75)